# Possible Unandled Promise Rejection

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, asyncstorage

I have implemented DrawerNavigator in my app and for Humberger icon and Logout icon, I have created below components :

```
 class HamburgerIcon extends Component {

  toggleDrawer = () => {

    console.log(this.props.navigationProps);

    this.props.navigationProps.toggleDrawer();

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggleDrawer.bind(this)} >
          <Image
            source={{ uri: 'https://reactnativecode.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/hamburger_icon.png' }}
            style={{ tintColor: '#fff', width: 25, height: 25, marginLeft: 5 }}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and :

```
class LogoutIcon extends Component {

  _signOutAsync = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.clear();
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Auth');
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._signOutAsync.bind(this)} >
          <Image style={{
            tintColor: '#fff', width: 25, height: 25, marginRight: 5
          }} source={require('./image/ic_logout.png')}></Image>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and I am getting error : **Possible Unandled Promise Rejection** on clicking on Logout icon.

As you can see inside LogoutIcon component, I have taken onPress as below :

```
onPress={this._signOutAsync.bind(this)}
```

What might be the issue ?

Thanks.

Comment: How about `onPress={this._signOutAsync()}`?

Comment: The code seems correct. Can you please provide some more details! Why don't you try debuggin it. Comment all your code inside _signOutAsync and simply just `console.log` see if the log appears. If the log appears then assign the await value to a const like this `const a = await AsyncStorage.clear()` log this value. You should probably be able to understand where the actual unhandled promise rejection is appearing.

Comment: @YashKalwani sir, The above commented error is coming due to : this.props.navigation.navigate('Auth'); .  clearing AsyncStorage is working fine.

Comment: @VishalZaptech this means that the props that your are passing to LogoutIcon is executing some async behaviour and the code snippet that you have provided is working correctly. Handle the async behaviour in your parent component that is causing this error.

Comment: ya, you are correct sir, and As you said of handling async behaviour in parent component.. How ?

Answer (score 0):

Relpace Your code

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggleDrawer.bind(this)} >
```

With Below code

```
<TouchableOpacity 
   onPress= { ()=> {
     AsyncStorage.clear().then(()=>
       this.props.navigation.navigate('Auth')
     ).catch((err)=>{
         console.log("ERROR", err)
     })
  } 
>
      ......

/* Remaining Code */
```

Comment: try to put alert in the .then block.    alert("TEST").  If alert is coming

Comment: done like this :   onPress= { ()=> {
       AsyncStorage.clear().then(()=>

       alert("TEST"),
       this.props.navigation.navigate('Auth'),
       
     ).catch((err)=>{
         console.log("ERROR", err)
     })
  ... Nothing coming;

Comment: Did you added the auth screen  to the stack navigator